# QListView currentIndex obsolete after layoutChanged()

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel

have following problem:

I have real model (Qt independent), which is able to report (through observer pattern) that it is changed, change can be absolutely anything (load of new file)

contract is (single thread):

- client obtains writable element from real model
- real model reports modified to observers, as writable item was obtained
- client does all changes that it needs and upon return, model needs to be in consistent state
- anything is free to update, as change is already done when it gets to execution

QModels are wrappers around this real model, and on modified emits layoutChanged

on qSignal lst...::selectionModel()::selectionChanged() I connected notify() like slot for QModels to behave as if real model changed (effectively they are dropping old state and computing new one), so they emit layoutChanged - this part seems to work ok

Now I have following problem, when model changes, all QModels emits layoutChanged, and when all is done, main loop gains control and tries to repaint relevant QListViews

the problem is, some of them depend on others,
for example:

- real model has houses/flats/chairs
- QModel wraps QHouses/QFlats/QChairs
- QListViews are lstHouses/lstFlats/lstChairs

how is it supposed to work

- QHouses just list all houses - top level
- QFlats shows flats from real model based on selection in lstHouses

  - QHouses->GetHouseReference(lstHouses->currentIndex())->GetFlats()
- QChairs shows chairs from real model based on selection in lstFlats

  - QFlats->GetFlatReference(lstFlats->currentIndex())->GetChairs()

problem is, when for example the very last house is selected, and real model decides to drop it, all QModels report layoutChanged and main loop (I think) attempts to paint all QListViews,

however I don't know hot to fix/force order, or ensure that listView updates based on model before returning from currentIndex()

what happens is, that lstHouses returns index pointing to the last row (no longer there) and index().isValid() returns true -> so it chrashes when attempting to retrieve value from real model from non-existing index

Any ideas how re these kind of scenarios solved?

Preemtpively call some DoSyncNow() before asking for QListView::currentIndex

Comment: Is there a way to make your real model deal more gracefully with requests for values from non-existing indices?  (if nothing else, it could keep the dropped house around for awhile in a special "to_be_deleted" list, rather than deleting it right away, so that any views still looking at that house would not crash.  You could then do the actual deletion of the dropped model data at some later time, when you are certain that no views are still looking at it)